# Run meteor methods in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a method

```
createDummyData: function (userId) {
  for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    Meteor.call('createA', userId, function (error, result) {
      for (var j=0; j<1000; j++) {
        Meteor.call('createB', userId, result._id);
        Meteor.call('createC', userId, result._id);
      }
    });
  }
},
```

where `createA` returns `A.insert({userId: userId})`.

As seen, the method calls other methods; however, it seems that `createA` is called 100 times, `createB` is called 100 times, and `createC` is not called at all.

I don't understand why `createB` is only called 100 times and not 100*1000 times. Will the methods run synchronously or something when they are called?

Comment: any console errors that are preventing `Meteor.call('createC'` from being called?  Are you sure it's getting called 100 times, not only writing 100 times.  Then 1000 j loop will try to create 1000 identical users so maybe it gives up after the first?

Comment: why are you using method calls on the server? why not just call the function directly?

Comment: How can I call methods within other methods? I have only read about `Meteor.call()`. Can I use `this.functionName(args)` or something?

Comment: Meteor.call is the portal to server-side functions for the the client. If these functions aren't used client-side then don't use Meteor.methods just make functions inside `if(Meteor.isServer)` or a server directory. -- In regards to the problem: It sounds like a 500 error, check your server logs.

Comment: But they are both used client-side and server-side. Normally, I use them client-side but I have just created a method to create dummy data, making it useful to call the other server-side functions